# Why AWS KMS cannot decrypt ciphertext of AWS Encryption SDK and vice versa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, openssl, iot, amazon-kms

I would like to better understand this

***On AWS Encryption SDK***

> The AWS Encryption SDK cannot decrypt the ciphertext that the AWS KMS Encrypt or ReEncrypt operations return. Similarly, the AWS KMS Decrypt operation cannot decrypt the encrypted message the AWS Encryption SDK returns.
> [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html)

***On AWS KMS***

> The Decrypt operation also decrypts ciphertext that was encrypted outside of AWS KMS by the public key in an AWS KMS asymmetric KMS key. However, it cannot decrypt ciphertext produced by other libraries, such as the AWS Encryption SDK or Amazon S3 client-side encryption. These libraries return a ciphertext format that is incompatible with AWS KMS.
> [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Decrypt.html)

My questions is :

1. If we choose the same standard algorithm, why the raw ciphertext will differs?
2. AWS KMS is already compatible with other libraries like OpenSSL but why AWS said "**it cannot decrypt ciphertext produced by other libraries**"? how to know the limit of compatibility with these libraries (like openssl bouncycastle, wolfssl, mbed TLS, etc.)?

Comment: To answer your first question, the AWS Encryption SDK doesn't just produce a "raw ciphertext" - it produces a complex binary message with multiple parts including wrapped keys, digital signatures etc. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/message-format.html AWS Encryption SDK also supports raw keys, multi-keyrings, etc which makes it completely different from the 'simple' KMS Encrypt API. You must think of the AWS Encryption SDK as being compatible only with itself, albeit there are implementations in multiple languages: C, Python, Java, etc

Comment: So we can retrieve the raw ciphertext thanks to parsing this format. AWS Encryption SDK is just wrapping it with keys and some other informations.
But what do you think @RichardHeap about second question for AWS KMS? Is this just because of incompatibility with AWS Encryption SDK and other AWS technologies?

Comment: No, because even though you could recover the raw ciphertext you wouldn't be able to use it since it is encrypted in a key derived from the data key via key commitment. It's also typically framed for plaintexts > 4096 bytes and the associated data contains values that you don't control. Don't know the answer to the second question. This feels like an XY problem.